# Working with files inside /tmp directory

Tags: php, tmp

I am trying to validate content of an uploaded .zip file and then save it to a desired directory.

My question is: can I rename, extract files inside `tmp/` directory? Will the files be removed automatically?

I would just like to know what happens to a file that I myself created in `tmp/` dir.

The current process is:

- Rename `tmp_name` to `...['tmp_name'].zip (if not exists)`
- Remove `...['tmp_name']` file.
- Extract zip to a folder name `...['tmp_name']`, file has already been deleted.
- Delete `.zip` file
- Validate contents inside folder.
- Move or delete extracted folder.

Comment: Yes it's possible but, the process follow by you is much better than what you are asking?

Comment: I would just like to know what happens to a file that I myself created in `tmp/` dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html):

> On most systems, this directory is cleared out at boot or at shutdown by the local system.

But as the documentation states, there is not much specified at the level of *Linux*, it depends on the distribution. Most servers don't reboot frequently, so the `/tmp` folder can become a mess that uses some (significant amount of) diskspace. Most Linux systems however allow to set the `TMPTIME` variable: the number of days a file can survive in `/tmp`. So by setting the variable to `1` files older than one day, are removed automatically (although probably not one second after they turn one day old). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up) for more details.

**Short answer**: the files are part of the file system. They normally are not removed automatically, only at reboot or when they are old enough. This to ensure that when you have to perform a few actions on the files, they don't disappear in the middle of it. Although one of course never fully knows.

You thus should make sure you give your files different names: if two processes happen concurrently, they should not interact. For instance use a random number so that the first file is named `zip151323.zip` and the second `zip4745443233.zip`.

Comment: So basically custom files created by user (can) be wiped by the system on reboot of the server; and uploaded files are wiped at the end of a script (as far as I know). If I can do my thing and be "Gone in Sixty Seconds" :), meaning that I delete all the stuff that I've created I should be ok?

Comment: Yes. But you thus need to delete the files manually (or wait for the OS to do it for you). But still you should make sure the filenames don't clash. Say two users upload a file almost concurrently, the two running scripts could conflict (for instance the first script is processing the unzipped content when the second script is unzipping the file and thus generating additional files in the directory).

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, because PHP already makes a unique filename for an uploaded file; The only thing I would have to watch out for is creating unique folder names when extracting. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It depends totally on your system and PHP configuration. This answer makes a number of assumptions which can't really be made. Check where your PHP configuration is pointing the files, check what you operating system does by default and how it is configured. You might end up posting on a different forum to check the details! For instance, whoever set up the OS, /may/ have added functionality to clean up the files. @CommuSoft doesn't actually know one way or the other. We don't even know if you're on Windows or Linux let alone distro/version/configuration!

Comment: @button I'm writin a PHP app module which would end up on different systems, but usually Linux servers.

Comment: @gskema Then you will want to specify in the documentation the requirements for the temporary folder that you use -- certainly if you are using it for anything beyond a quick processing. I find the answer above slightly misleading in this respect, it suggest that PHP will  back you up in this regard, which it won't.

Comment: @button: where do you read this. It always says "most distributions" and even explicitly says "not much is specified", except the POSIX standard of course... PHP is not mentioned at all...

Comment: @button It is (kind of) quick processing: extract .zip archive, validate ~100 image, xml files and then move or delete folder and other created files.

Comment: @CommuSoft the question is about behaviour exposed by PHP that PHP doesn't have control over. The answer is really 'nobody knows'. But the advice is that normally it's on boot for Linux distros (I haven't the faintest idea for Windows though...). For instance PHP doesn't have to use /tmp, you could tell it to go somewhere else entirely if you so chose. ~~ In this specific case the question is asked by someone who doesn't control the OS or its behaviour; thus the best advice that I can give is to state what the library being build requires such that it can be used without problems.

Comment: With my less conscientious hat on, I'd they'd be fine just not worrying about it as long as the library is cleaning up after itself. But that's their decision to make, with the best possible information we can provide :p.

Comment: @button: the question comes down to: "what happens with files in the `/tmp` folder" whether these files originate from a PHP script or Haskell is irrelevant. The answer is "that one cannot say much about it in general". But the Linux documentation explicitly states that is asks distributions to at least remove files at boot time.

Comment: @CommuSoft I agree to disagree on the interpretation of the question :). As far as I can tell we're pretty much saying the same thing but from different perspectives. The /tmp directory cannot be used on Windows AFAIK, so the PHP side of it does have some importance from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your operating system and PHP configuration. PHP isn't managing the file system and this directory could be added by any application.

From http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir :

> upload_tmp_dir string The temporary directory used for storing files
>   when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is
>   running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.
>
> If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the
>   system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the
>   system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

So in short, it's up to your operating system and configuration as this is just a pointer to a folder somewhere in your system -- PHP will not manage this for you. Many will only delete the files on startup, so you should probably be careful to clean up after unzipping (or use something to clean up any garbage).

If creating a library or module for general re-use then you will want to specify in the documentation the requirements for the temporary folder that you use -- certainly if you are using it for anything beyond a quick processing. (I.e. you'll probably get away with just writing the code and forgetting about it, but if you want to stay on the safe side...).